# Put a color on <area> in imagemap not hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

> how to put a background on area of image map i use color='#C93434' but nothing happen what should i do ? this is not hover trick i just want a a color on the area.

```
 <img name="n12170429_1057987957553205_216639343_n1"  class="mapper" src="teeth.jpg" width="550" height="447" id="n12170429_1057987957553205_216639343_n1" usemap="#m_12170429_1057987957553205_216639343_n201" alt="" /><map name="m_12170429_1057987957553205_216639343_n201" id="m_12170429_1057987957553205_216639343_n201">
        <area shape="poly" color="#C93535" coords="381,326,372,325,364,326,360,331,356" href="javascript:;" alt="" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="338,356,335,352" href="javascript:;" alt="" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="323,358,311,360,304" href="javascript:;" alt="" />
```

Comment: Do you use imagemapster? http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html You can set the background-color, stroke or opacity with it. Just simple area html tag doesn't have this kind of parameters: http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/area.html